# JavaScript: create variable from part of useragent

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

So I have kiosks in stores running Sitekiosk, on these kiosks I append the useragent as `utm_source` to urls in a page, for tracking in Google Analytics. We have sitekiosk broadcasting the name of the machine in the useragent, e.g.

```
utm_source=Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1;%20WOW64;%20Trident/7.0;%20rv:11.0;%20SiteKiosk%209.5%20Build%204117;%20MACHINE10%20shopkiosk)
```

`MACHINE10` being the identifier of the kiosk in the store.

Using this complete useragent to append to the url was easy. I created a variable from the useragent and add it to the urls:

```
var machine=navigator.userAgent;
```

A long `utm_source` like this is not very readable in Google Analytics (and messes up my reports), so I'm looking for a way to not append the full useragent, but only the `MACHINE10` part.

Is there a way to use only that part of the useragent in the variable? One issue here is that not all machines have 2 digits in the name, some have 3 digits. Rest of the useragent is the same for all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression for grabbing the number of the machine:

```
//Looks through the string until it finds the word MACHINE, then captures
//any amount of digits up to hitting the percentage sign
const regEx = /.*?MACHINE(\d+)%.*?/;
//Grab the capture groups
const captures = regEx.exec(navigator.userAgent);
//Set the last capture group value to variable which is the machine #
const machineNum = captures[captures.length - 1];
```

Comment: thanks. How do I use this `const` in a url?. I currently use `var someURL =  "https://www.example.com/?utm_source="+machine+"&utm_medium="medium"&utm_content="content";`

Comment: If I use your suggestion, I get an error in my console that machineNum is not defined.

Hope you can help. I'm quite 'fresh' at JS.

Comment: 'const' is another way of declaring a variable, it means that the variable's value cannot be changed. As far as you receiving an error, I'd have to see your updated code using my answer above to try and find the problem.

Comment: I currently have 
`//Looks through the string until it finds the word MACHINE, then captures any amount of digits up to hitting the percentage sign

const regEx = /.*?MACHINE(\d+)%.*?/;

//Grab the capture groups

const captures = regEx.exec(navigator.userAgent);

//Set the last capture group value to variable which is the machine #

const machineNum = machineNum[machineNum.length - 1];

var someURL = "https://example.com/?utm_source="+machineNum+"&utm_medium=medium";`

Which evaluates in the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Change this line: const machineNum = machineNum[machineNum.length -1] to const machineNum = captures[captures.length - 1];